# How to handle KeyEvent's for each ViewPart or Form in SWT/JFace?

Tags: java, event-handling, swt, jface

I'm building an Eclipse application and I'm trying to make a shortcut for launching an action when pressing F5, and make that the default action when that `Tab`/`ViewPart` has the focus.

I have read that this is not possible, or very complex. Is there any simple/straight way of doing it?

I tried with:

```
Display.getCurrent().addFilter(...)
this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {...})
```

...

Making this in the constructor is my best:

```
this.getShell().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.keyCode == SWT.F5) {
            //doAnything()
        }
    }
});
```

And this doesn't work when loaded, but if I switch from this to another `View`/`Tab` starts to work. But it works too when others have focus (which I don't want).

Is there anyway of making this work at the start, and only when the focus is in the `View`?

Comment: Didn't you satisfied with the answers here? Please accept answers.

Comment: I almost got it. My only problem is making it work with F12, which is an Eclipse default key, but I'm unable to override Eclipse default scheme.

I have made this specific question in other post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358904/eclipse-rcp-overriding-scheme-doesnt-work-for-key-bindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define work in a [handler](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/commands/AbstractHandler.html) & then should use key bindings as given in this example. You can find a good example [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommandsKeybindings/article.html). Hope it solves your need.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [RetargetableActions](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/wrkAdv_retarget.htm).  I think that's Eclipse way of doing it:

Comment: It seems that this is useful for MenuBars, but not for catching keystrokes. If the Vogella way doesn't work, I will try this one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the listener of the events of the component it will listen on the events. And if the event occur for this component it will be notified.

To add listener of the key event on the `ViewPart` we should create the control which could be able listen on the event.

```
public class SampleView extends ViewPart {
  /**
   * The ID of the view as specified by the extension.
   */
  public static final String ID = "views.SampleView";

  private Composite mycomposite;

  public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    mycomposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.FILL);

//then add listener

    mycomposite.addKeyListener(keyListener);
  }

  private KeyListener keyListener = new KeyAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        showMessage("key pressed: "+ e.keyCode);                
    }
  };

//the rest of focusing and handle event

  private void showMessage(String message) {
    MessageDialog.openInformation(
        mycomposite.getShell(),
        "Sample View",
        message);
  }

  /**
   * Passing the focus request to the viewer's control.
   */
  public void setFocus() {
    mycomposite.setFocus();
  }
}
//the end
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing this in a button, for example, doesn't work if the button has no focus. I'm asked to do it no matter where the focus is.

Comment: @madtyn You should put it on concrete view/tab, why this button?

Comment: I didn't explain myself properly. I tried adding a KeyListener on a Composite as well as on the corresponding Shell, but only worked on the Shell and having the strange behaviour I described at the start of this page.

Comment: It's not strange but normal behavior because you have used the listener of the parent object and event is propagated to all children who listens of that kind of event.

Comment: But when I use the listener on the Composite containing the desired components (the one inside the ViewPart) instead of the Shell, it does not work. Why?

Shouldn't this be the same?

Comment: @madtyn I have created a sample code that let you look why and how to add a listener of the event to the `Composite`

Comment: I looked at your sample, but I think that's not the best of doing it in a RCP app. Looks good for raw SWT/JFace, but when dealing with inherited key schemes from Eclipse and so, you are going to need to modify the xml configs of Eclipse.

Thank you very much. Sorry for the lateness.

Comment: I think I understand why lateness. You sated that you cannot put listener on the ViewPart. And you are ignored my point since you got other investigation subject. Once you got learned you've unresolved issue in mind. That's why you wrote that. And my point was only show you that you was mistaken. But you just ignored. But what's sad that my effort was not to solve your mind problem but to have an answer that closely corresponds to a question.

Comment: You're right in some points but not in another. I was following another way of doing it first (the www.vogella.com way). But also I had much work on a couple of weeks with another priorities.

I came back to this when I got some free time.

If this issue has disturbed you, I'm sorry. Didn't want to bother you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at extensions  `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` and `org.eclipse.ui.contexts`.

1. Define a command and its handler
2. Define a binding for the command
3. define context (cxtId)
4. associate context with command so that command is available only when context is active
5. Activate context when you open the view or form.

Comment: Looking on the previous comment added to yours, I think I have doubts only at your point number 5.

How do I activate context when opening the view/form?

Comment: IContextService service = (IContextService) getSite().getService(IContextService.class);  use service.activeContext(contextId) and deactiveContext(Context)

Comment: I have just read the last comment. Thank you very much. I can't vote comments yet, but you can be sure I'm grateful for this.

Comment: I'm almost there but I fail to override Eclipse's default scheme. I considered this on another question, because it's a different issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358904/eclipse-rcp-overriding-scheme-doesnt-work-for-key-bindings